# Create delay time for next trigger/ring

Tags: switches, timer, delay

I'm interested in a push switch (220-240 V) which when assigned to a specific time (let's assume the delay is 15 s and the application is a doorbell).

Scenario: Guest arrives and pushes or holds or presses the push button to ring the doorbell. As long as the button is pushed and held or as soon as the button is pressed and released the timer starts for 15 s. In this time if the guest presses the button it shall not trigger the doorbell since the delay from the last trigger is within the delay.

Application for this system is because,
I'm from a place where the electrician, postman, government staff, guests, etc. will be in hurry and don't want to wait untill the door is attended and keep on ringing the bell every second which irritates us.

Comment: I have always felt impatient humans need debouncing.

Comment: Doorbells are not at the mains voltage for safety reasons. 12 is typical. This does make solutions easier.